# For each in c++ and assigning values to std::vector

Tags: c++, foreach

How can I assign values to elements of `std::vector` using "for each" instruction?
I tried to do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> A(5);
for each(auto& a in A)
    a = 4;
```

But then I get the following error:

```
error C3892 : 'a' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

Comment: try `std::transform` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

Comment: I assume you meant `for (...)` instead of `for each(...)`. Also, there's no `in` keyword there, just `for (auto& a : A)`.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're using Qt `foreach`, `std::for_each` or simply `for(...)`, but it most closely resembles the latter.  Your second line would be `for(auto& a : A)`.

Comment: For C++03, use `std::fill`; for C++09,use `std::fill` or `for(auto& a:A) a=4`; but here why not use `std::vector<int> A(5, 4)`?

Comment: If your goal is really to learn how for_each can be used then please clarify that.  If your goal is simply to learn the various ways to loop on a vector to set its values then there are other options for that and for_each isn't the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The for_each algorithm does not seem appropriate for that type of problem.  Let me know if I am misunderstanding the issue.

```
    // You can set each value to the same during construction
    std::vector<int> A(10, 4);  // 10 elements all equal to 4

    // post construction, you can use std::fill
    std::fill(A.begin(), A.end(), 4);

    // or if you need different values via a predicate function or functor
    std::generate(A.begin(), A.end(), predicate);

    // if you really want to loop, you can do that too if your compiler 
    // supports it VS2010 does not yet support this way but the above 
    // options have been part of the STL for many years.

    for (int &i : A) i = 4;
```

Personally, I have not ever found a good use for the for_each algorithm.  It must be good for something because it was put into the library but I have never needed it in over 10 years of C++ programming.  That one isn't particularly useful in my opinion.

Comment: If all that's required is to set each value to 4, it can collapse to a single line:  `std::vector<int> A(5,4);`

Comment: That's true if it only needs to be done at the beginning of its life. I was in a hurry and was interrupted as I was typing in the answer so I had to keep it short but I'll add some more options to the answer.